# Pass a date input value from View to Controller using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to give the user to select the date he wants, and it will display the reservations for the day he selected. I am using Codeigniter, the MVC framework.

1. How am I setting a default value of the current date for an input date selection?
2. How am I sending the value to the controller and then I am using it for a function in the model.

```
<form id="form_reDate" name="form_reDate" method="POST" action="form_reDate.php">
 <?php $r_date=@date('d-m-y'); ?>  
    <label for="reservations">Display reservations for :
    <input type="date" id="date" name="re_date" style="margin-left: 0;"
                       min="2020-01-01" max="2020-12-31" value="<?php $r_date?>">
   </label>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function form_reDate(){

        $newDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post('re_date')));
        $data['tables'] = $this->Hosting_model->get_tables($newDate);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the default html of input `type="date"` to set its value you only use this php code.

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>
```

to sum it:

```
<input type="date" id="date" name="re_date" style="margin-left: 0;"
                   min="2020-01-01" max="2020-12-31" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>">
```

and for question #2 on how to send your input value to your Controller. Just make sure you get the data before sending it to your Model.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I need the reservations to be displayed when I select the date, should I use JS ?

Comment: @Victoria'sSecret you can use both JS and PHP.